# Error saying that SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-2.7

When I run my python code I am receiving an invalid syntax for the mapper.py

```
>>> python mapper.py|sort|reducer.py|
```

the mapper.py work on its own after I run the program but I am trying to do a mapReduce.

Answer (score 0):

`>>>` means that you are in the python terminal. You need to go out from there using command `exit()`. After that use `python mapper.py` within your usual console.

Comment: @Formalhaut, Can you explain your second sentence